# Why doesn't my sonar scanner run create a report-task.txt file?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to get my build to break based on sonar results - so I've got a build-breaker running off the results in `report-task.txt`.

I'm running sonar in maven - with the following plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</plugin>
```

And the following command:

```
mvn  -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.scm.enabled=false -Dsonar.scm-stats.enabled=false -Dsonar.working.directory=/mypath/target/.sonar
```

Now I expect the `report-task.txt` to be created in `/mypath/target/.sonar` but it is not.

**SonarQube version: Version 5.5**

My question is: **Why doesn't my sonar scanner run  create a report-task.txt file?**

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: SonarQube has posted a [Why You Shouldn’t Use Build Breaker](http://www.sonarqube.org/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/) article. It seems that [SonarQube 5.4](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE54/Breaking+the+CI+Build) is last the version supporting it.

Comment: That's an interesting article - I could say quite a bit about it. Let's assume for the purpose of this question I've already read it, and still need a build breaker solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what is stopping it:

```
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
```

You have to change it to:

```
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=
```

The assumption being you will have to upload bad builds and then trap them with a leak-period of 3 days instead of previous version.

Comment: Why empty instead of "publish"?

Comment: Where to add this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If your version is greater than 6.6 use analysis parameter 
sonar.working.directory=path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of not finding the report where I expected, in my case it was because the default report path for sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1+SonarQube server 9.9 was `target/sonar/report-task.txt`.